# Html5 or Jquery Responsive Monthly Gantt chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, html, charts

I need a way to achieve the following chart :
[agents status table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCE8l.png)

Each red rectangle represents the time an agent was on board a vessel during a day (or days) in the specified month. When a user moves the mouse over a red rectangle, it displays the vessel's name, boarding date/time and disembarking date/time.

Does anybody knows if there is a jquery plugin and/or an html5 way to achieve this? I need it to retrieve the data from a mysql table, but what i care the most is the chart design.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What did google throw up?

Comment: Many Gantt charts plugins but for project tasks like MS Project. I got tired googling so that's why i ended up here. Thanks.